# Bike Size Question - Kestrel Talon

Tags: bike-fit, bike-selection

For my goals, I am looking at a Kestrel Talon 2015 as it fits my price point and I like the combination of road cycling or switching to tri fit (albeit jack of all trades but master of none).

I am now trying to figure out if the Kestrel will fit my body dimensions (following the Eddie fit). From what I've read, sure being able to stand over the bike is important, but it seems the effective top tube length is most critical. I know the best advice is to try the Kestrel out at a LBS, but there are none near me.

I followed the measurements on `competitivecyclist.com` and here are my specs:

```
Your Measurements   
Inseam: 75
Trunk: 62
Forearm: 32
Arm: 55
Thigh: 54
Lower Leg: 48.5
Sternal Notch: 137.5
Total Body Height: 166


The Eddy Fit (cm)
Seat Tube Range c–c: 49.8 - 50.2 cm
Seat Tube Range c–t: 51.2 - 51.8 cm
Top Tube Length: 50.8 - 51.2 cm
Stem Length: 9.1 - 9.7 cm
BB–Saddle Position: 63.2 - 65.2 cm
Saddle Handlebar: 48.5 - 49.1 cm
Saddle Setback: 4 - 4.4 cm
```

For the Kestrel Talon, here are the [specs](http://www.kestrelbicycles.com/road/talon-road-shimano-105). I'm stuck between the 48 cm & 52 cm frames.

I think the 48 cm frame's top tube, the effective top tube length is 51 cm, which is I think very close to what the Eddy fit says.

I think I'm leaning more towards the 48 cm, but not too sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably look at a different model of bike. At the smaller end of sizes for 700c bikes (e.g. most 48 cm ish bikes), you'd be better off buying a 650b bike. There is a personal preference in which size of bike you want.

Comment: The first rule of bike sizing, when fitting a conventional "diamond" frame, is that you should be able to comfortably stand, flat-footed, while straddling the bike's top tube.  (With an unconventional frame you envision where the top tube *would* be, and you imagine straddling that.)  This is the "stand-over" height (and bike specs hardly ever include it, so you have to compute/estimate it somehow).

Comment: @DanielRHicks: these days, standover height is listed in the "geometry" table present on the webpages of virtually all major bike makers.